# SQL reader read table 2 data using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 2 select statement in my stored procedure,im using sql reader to read my data,below is my codes,i wish to read 2nd table,any idea how to do it?

```
public BOL.HomeAnnouncement get_total(string subs_cd, string timee)
{
    oConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    oConnection.Open();
    BOL.HomeAnnouncement t_list = new BOL.HomeAnnouncement();
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand();
    oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.CommandText = "TMS";
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SUBS", subs_cd));
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time_in", timee));
    SqlDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        t_list.Name = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Total_Employee")) ? "" : oReader["Total_Employee"].ToString();
        t_list.status = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Total_Present")) ? "" : oReader["Total_Present"].ToString();
        t_list.Title = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Total_Absent")) ? "" : oReader["Total_Absent"].ToString();
    }
    oReader.Close();
    oConnection.Close();
    return t_list;
}


  t_list.Name = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Table2.Total_Employee")) ? "" : oReader["Table2.Total_Employee"].ToString();
  t_list.status = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Table2.Total_Present")) ? "" : oReader["Table2.Total_Present"].ToString();
  t_list.Title = oReader.IsDBNull(oReader.GetOrdinal("Table2.Total_Absent")) ? "" : oReader["Table2.Total_Absent"].ToString();
```

tried this but not working.. table2.Total_Employee

**EDIT**

Error returned:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Table2.Total_Employee
```

Comment: Which error you have? Please post the SP code too

Comment: @JoeTaras System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Table2.Total_Employee

Comment: Your column doesn't not exists, Please post SP code

Comment: You should really wrap all your instances that are of types that implement `IDisposable` in `using` blocks. In this case it will make sure your database connections will always be cleaned. See [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements)

Answer (score 0):

After error occurs:

**Error cause:**

This exception has returned bur method `GetOrdinal` of `SqlDataReader` when column you passed as parameter doesn't exist.

If you go [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read the MSDN explanation.

**Solution:**

I suppose your stored procedure output is different respect field you want to use in `SqlDataReader`. Please post your stored procedure code for further help